# JW Player - Stop (target) Multiple Players with an Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I have a click handler to fire the built in `jwplayer().stop();` functionality. However only my first handler executes and the other one fails (but no errors are logged).

The videos are embedded into the element divs in the view.

In another words: I can stop the first video but not the second, third and so on even though I'm able to log every subsequent click inside my `function()`.

Thoughts?
Thank you.

```
$(function(){
    console.log('ready');
    $('.stop').on('click',function stopVideo () {
       //stop JW player
        if (typeof(jwplayer) != 'undefined') {
                console.log('video stopped');
                jwplayer().stop();

            }         
    })
});
```

view

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- first video -->
    <div class="jw" style="width: 40%; margin: 10px auto">
        <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/4sng2RGX-UQtQ90mG.js"></script>
        <button class="stop" style="padding: 8px 19px; float: right; margin: 10px">stop video</button>
    </div>

    <!-- second video -->
    <div class="jw" style="width: 40%; margin: 10px auto">
        <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/z5Jka98V-UQtQ90mG.js"></script>
        <button class="stop" style="padding: 8px 19px; float: right; margin: 10px">stop video</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per JW documentation under **Targeting Multiple Players**:

> Not including an ID or index with your API call will always target the first player on a page.
>   https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/javascript_api_introduction/

Here's a solution:

```
$(function(){
    //get every video with class .stopVideo
    var count = $('.stopVideo').length;

    $('#stop').on('click',function() {
       //loop through all videos stored in count
       for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (typeof(jwplayer) != 'undefined') {
                console.log('video stopped');
                //stop player
                jwplayer(i).stop();

            } 
        }        
    })
});
```

view

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- first video -->
    <div class="stopVideo">
        <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/4sng2RGX-UQtQ90mG.js"></script>
    </div>

    <!-- second video -->
    <div class="stopVideo">
        <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/z5Jka98V-UQtQ90mG.js"></script>
    </div>
    <button id="stop">stop video</button>
</div>
</body>
```

I agree that's unfortunate when someone votes a question down without giving a reason for it. Keep it up and Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much @Null is True. I really appreciate the insight.

Comment: Yeah no prob @tonkihonks13

Answer (score 1):

Your `stopVideo()` function has no way of knowing which video is it supposed to stop. `jwplayer` is just some global variable that may or may not be related to the button that you're clicking on.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Do you have a suggestion where I can bind the stoppage of all videos via the click handler? Even if using a different approach than jwplayer().stop()?

Comment: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/javascript_api_introduction/ -- scroll down to `targeting multiple players`, should put you on the right track.